# Is this proof that $1+a^2$ is never divisible by a 3 mod 4 prime complete and correct?

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

I think I've found a neat and straightforward proof of the fact that the expression

$$a^2 + 1$$

is never divisible by a 3 mod 4 prime factor for any integer $a$. I would like someone to review it and determine whether it's complete and correct.

1: Any integer divisible by a 3 mod 4 prime can be expressed in the form $(4b+3)c$, where $(b,c)$ is a pair of integers. Additionally, $b$ is a non-negative integer.

2: Assuming that $a^2 + 1$ is divisible by a 3 mod 4 prime, this means that $a^2 + 1 = (4b + 3)c$ for some $(b,c)$ satisfying 1.

3: The right hand side of the equation can be rearranged as

$$4c * b + 3c$$

so the equation states that dividing the left hand side by $4c$ shall give the remainder $3c$. This is the final remainder for dividing by $4c$, since
$3c < 4c$ for any positive integer $c$, and $c$ must be positive to make the right hand side positive since the left hand side is positive.

4: WLOG, let $a = 4c * d + e$ for some pair of integers $(d,e)$. The left-hand side is now equal to

$$(4cd + e)^2 + 1 = 4c(4cd^2 + 2de) + (e^2 + 1)$$

We must equal the remainder in 3, so $e^2 + 1 = 3c$. Therefore, $e^2 + 1$ must be divisible by 3.

5: WLOG, let $e = 3f + g$ for some pair of integers $(f,g)$, where $0 <= g <= 2$. This gives

$e^2 + 1 = (3f + g)^2 + 1 = 3(3f^2 + 2fg) + (g^2 + 1)$

so $g^2 + 1$ must be divisible by 3. Plugging in the possible values of $g$, we get the following mod 3 congruence values for this expression:

$$0^2 + 1 = 1 mod 3$$
$$1^2 + 1 = 2 mod 3$$
$$2^2 + 1 = 5 = 2 mod 3$$

This shows that $g^2 + 1$ is never divisible by 3, so we get a contradiction against our assumption. Therefore, $a^2 + 1$ is never divisible by a 3 mod 4 prime. It would be nice to get some suggestions on how this proof can be shortened.

Comment: The assertion $3 \mid e^2+1$ doesn't seem correct.

Comment: "We must equal the remainder in 3, so $e^2+1=3c$." It is not guaranteed that $e^2+1<4c$, only that $e<4c$, so all you can say is that $e^2+1\equiv 3c \mod 4c$.

Comment: So essentially I've done nothing except make a generalization with a clear bound with regards to $c$?

Comment: Step 4: We do NOT know that $e^2+1=3c.$ All we know is that $e^2+1$ divided by $4c$ leaves a remainder of $3c:$ There exists integer $x$ such that $e^2+1=x(4c)+3c.$ That does not imply that $3$ divides $e^2+1.$ ... Taking all values to be non-negative,  we can suppose from $a=4cd+e$ that $e\leq 4c-1,$  implying $e^2+1\leq (4c-1)^2+1.$ But we cannot infer,  from this, that $e^2+1=3c.$